# Delaying the Removal of Elements with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to create a detailed animation using Raphael that has multiple scenes, but I've run into an issue; how can I delay the removal of elements if I want to move onto another scene? In my animation, the first "scene" is of four seals popping out of a body of water, after which I want them to be underwater, which would require the removal of unneeded elements from that scene. I'm not sure however how to remove those elements at the time that the first scene ends. The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is by cheating and animating them off the page. Also, is there a way to group elements together from the first scene and then remove that group instead of having to remove them all individually? Here's what I have so far:

```
window.onload = function (){

    var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 800, 600);

    var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,800,600).attr({ fill: "90-white:60-#9dc8f3", stroke : "none"});

    var sun = paper.circle (400, 300, 60).attr({ fill: "90-orange-yellow", stroke : "none"})

    var water1 = paper.rect(0,200,800,400).attr({ fill: "#2e659c", stroke : "none"});

    var seal1 = paper.image("sealright.png", 190, 270, 140, 175);

    var water2 = paper.rect(0,280,800,400).attr({ fill: "#2e659c", stroke : "none"});

    var seal2 = paper.image("sealleft.png", 430, 350, 180, 225);

    var water3 = paper.rect(0,360,800,400).attr({ fill: "#2e659c", stroke : "none"});

    var seal3 = paper.image("sealright.png", 70, 430, 220, 275);

    var water4 = paper.rect(0,440,800,400).attr({ fill: "#2e659c", stroke : "none"});

    var seal4 = paper.image("shadeseal.png", 460, 510, 260, 327);

    var water5 = paper.rect(0,520,800,400).attr({ fill: "#2e659c", stroke : "none"});

    var iceright = paper.image("icerights.png", 584, 198, 276, 246.5);

    var iceleft = paper.image("icelefts.png", -60, 198, 276, 246.5);

    var opac = paper.rect(0,0,800,600).attr({ fill: "white", "fill-opacity": "0.4",stroke : "none"});

    var playButton = paper.path("M 300 180 R 500 300 300 420 z");

playButton.attr({fill: '#eff', stroke: '#9df', 'stroke-width': 10});

playButton.hover(function () {
    playButton.attr({"stroke": "#fff"});
  },
  function () {
    playButton.attr({"stroke": "#9df"});
  }
);

var sunanim = Raphael.animation({cy : 100, opacity: "0.4"}, 1000, "elastic");

var sealanim = Raphael.animation({y : 170}, 300, "backOut");

var sealanim2 = Raphael.animation({y : 210}, 300, "backOut");

var sealanim3 = Raphael.animation({y : 260}, 300, "backOut");

var sealanim4 = Raphael.animation({y : 310}, 300, "backOut");


var backgroundchange1 = Raphael.animation({ fill: "90-#0d0e46-#0b94da"}, 0);


function musicStart(){
    opac.remove();

    var clickSound = new Audio('Funk-tabulous.mp3');

    clickSound.play();
};

function musicStart(){
    opac.remove();

    var clickSound = new Audio('Funk-tabulous.mp3');

    clickSound.play();
};

function anim(){
    sun.animate(sunanim.delay(1000))

    seal1.animate(sealanim.delay(2000));

    seal2.animate(sealanim2.delay(2400));

    seal3.animate(sealanim3.delay(2800));

    seal4.animate(sealanim4.delay(3200));
};

function remove(){
    sun.remove();
};

function anim2(){
    backGround.animate(backgroundchange1.delay(3800));
};

function animation(){
    playButton.remove();

    musicStart();

    anim();

    anim2();
};

playButton.click(function(){
    animation();
});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just hide the element (otherwise you could use this same principle and make the function actually remove the element, the 4th animate element is a callback). So here is a combination that sequences a move after another move followed by a hide. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbvm/3/

```
var paper = new Raphael(100,0,2000,2000);
var rect = paper.rect(50,50,50,50);
var rect2 = paper.rect(100,100,100,100);
var set = paper.set();
set.push( rect, rect2 );

var animation = Raphael.animation({ x: 200 },200,"linear", animateCircle);

set.animate( animation );

var circle = paper.circle(50,50,50);
function animateCircle() {
    circle.animate({ cx : 200 }, 200, "linear", hideCircle);
};

function hideCircle() {
    set.hide();
}
```

Edit: I've updated a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbvm/8/ to move a set as well